# Как запустить xgboost на gpu

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, cuda, gpu, xgboost

```
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=i, n_estimators=j, tree_method = 'hist', device='CUDA')
```

Выдает ошибку:

[10:43:19] WARNING: C:\Users\dev-admin\croot2\xgboost-split_1675461376218\work\src\learner.cc:767:
Parameters: { "device" } are not used.

Если прописать вот так:

```
model = xgb.XGBRegressor(max_depth=i, n_estimators=j, tree_method = 'gpu_hist')
```

То

c:\users\dev-admin\croot2\xgboost-split_1675461376218\work\src\common\common.h:239: XGBoost version not compiled with GPU support.

В чем собственно проблема? CUDA установлено, но в диспетчере задач не отображается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка вам выдаётся достаточно информативная.

> XGBoost version not compiled with GPU support.

Установленная у вас версия библиотеки `XGBoost` скомпилирована без поддержки `GPU`. Вам нужно установить другую версию библиотеки - с поддержкой `GPU`. Это типичная ситуация для многих библиотек. Поддержка `GPU` сильно "раздувает" библиотеку, поэтому обычно выпускают отдельно версии библиотеки для `CPU` и для `GPU`.

Пример из [документации](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) установки `GPU` версии через `conda`:

```py
conda install -c conda-forge py-xgboost-gpu
```

Comment: Для винды такой способ не поможет. Решил проблему установкой xgboost через !pip install xgboost непосредственно в jupyter

Comment: Странно, обычно в винде через `conda` нормально ставится всё.

Comment: `py-xgboost-gpu` not available on Windows.

The `py-xgboost-gpu` is currently not available on Windows. If you are using Windows, please use `pip` to install XGBoost with GPU support.

Не увидел это, возможно, старые версии так и устанавливались...